# retrieve content from html span tag in a twig loop using jquery

Tags: jquery, symfony, twig

i am using symfony 3.4 , i have a list of objects that i am looping it in order to display these objects details in  a twig loop , here is the twig code :

```
     {% for  offre in listeoffres  %}
 <button id="wishlist" class="btn">add to wishlist</button>
              <div id="offerid">
                     <span> {{offre.id}}</span>
                </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

the twig loop is displaying the list objects correctly , in my jquery code i want "on a click of the button" to retreive the content of the span of the clicked object (offer) , the problem is when i try to retreive that value using jquery i don't get the value of the clicked one but i always get the value of the first object of the list but not the concerned one . this is my jquery code :

```
    <script>
        $('.btn').click( function(){
            var personnage = $('#offerid span').html();
            alert(personnage);

        });
    </script>
```

the alert is displaying always only the span content of the first object of the list but not the clicked one .

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page...they are unique by definition

Comment: @charlietfl that's not the context of the post , by the way not only the id even the other attributes the same situation you only get the first object values and the id is just for test issues

Comment: So you need to traverse to `next()` to get the right span after you change repeating ID's to clsses

Comment: that's a static value retreive , i want to dynimically get the clicked one

Comment: Yes... starting from `this` in the event handler

Comment: please can you clarify more your idea or post it as an answer if you are sure about it

Comment: What @charlietfl said is correct. You need unique `id's` and that is why you only get the first object value... Even if the id is just for "testing". It is why you are having this error!

Answer (score 1):

Use `next()` to get the associated `<div>` and then `find()` for the `<span>`.

Make sure to change repeating ID's to classes

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  var personnage = $(this).next().find('span').html();
  alert(personnage);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="" class="wishlist btn">add to wishlist</button>
<div class="offerid">
  <span> {{offre.id}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but it's not working like that  it's printing an undefined value